# How can I tell the compiler to select the faster of two implementations?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

Suppose I have two possible code paths. Let's say they even have observably different (i.e. they return different output). I want to use the path that is faster. As I do not know which of them is faster, the compiler should select the one it considers to be preferable. How can I tell the compiler to do that for me?

Consider this simplified example:

```
int F (int i) {
    if (this is more likely to be faster in some current environment) {
        return i * i;
    } else {
        return i * 2 + 1;
    }
}
```

Both code paths are valid solutions. Yes, they return different results. That is fine, as long as only a single path is chosen during the runtime of the program. I simply want the compiler to select the one that is probably faster. I realize this is an unusual scenario.

I'm using gcc, clang and msvc, but any compiler is fine, as long as it supports this scenario.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why someone would put this option into a compiler. What's the use case?

Comment: Perhaps you could benchmark various representative inputs with both paths and then decide how to programmatically determine which to execute at runtime for a given input. Alternatively, run them in concurrent threads and use the result of the faster-completing thread though you'd have to validate this approach (it could make things worse in some cases). Or ... quantum computer ;-)

Comment: I had a valid use case some years ago, tho I sadly forgot what exactly it was. It was in the area of high performance computing.

Comment: `if ... else` is decided at runtime, not by the compiler. You might need `#if ... #else ... #endif`.

Comment: Well, with any compiler I am familiar it would be the job of the programmer.  You will define a bunch of `#ifdefs` for different architectures you are supporting, and will put the "fastest" one for each. You will have to determine which one before, of course.

Comment: @jarmod In simple cases, yes. Either I look up the cycle counts or I benchmark. But I'm interested in more complex scenarios that are difficult to benchmark. Instead, I want to leverage the expertise of the compiler.

Comment: How could they both be valid solutions if they return different results?

Comment: @Barmar Any reason. Let's say they return random numbers and I want to select the faster of two implementations.

Comment: @Barmar Well, I guess for a program that would output `i*2` when it is considering faster, or `i*2+1` otherwise :)

Comment: These days wwe mostly depend on compiler optimizations. If the compiler is smart enough to figure out which one is faster, it may be able to optimize the slower one to the faster one.[

Comment: @Barmar No, that's the problem. They behave differently, so the compiler cannot optimize one to the other. Unless I tell it to. And how to do that is exactly the question.

Comment: "They behave differently..." Well that's a big problem. A function which behaves differently when called with the same input data are not something any user of your function can come to depend on. That it behaves in certain way in certain situations, and that the same input can give different results, needs to be ***very*** well documented.

Comment: @mafu OK, let's say we have such an option. Now, as a programmer, how would you tell looking at the code what it is supposed to do without knowing the exact internals of the specific architecture variant? Even on two different x86's the execution times of both paths can be different.

Comment: And you can't really compare this function to a random-number generator, because even a PRNG function should give the same result for the same input (seed).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Indeed. That is why I am asking an expert, i.e. the compiler :)

Comment: @mafu You can't ask the compiler if you are given a printout of the code and asked what it is doing. Again, the compiler will emit the exact same code for all the x86's (for example), but it can run on very different hardware.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is a nondeterministic, poorly written RNG that generates number according to one of two documented algorithms. Use your imagination! :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. How do you mean? As far as I know, compilers are aware of the execution characteristics of code on a certain platform, i.e. which of several options (e.g. mul by 3 or shift left and add) is faster.

Comment: @mafu If you buy a software that is claimed to run on x86 under Windows <whatever>, you will be able to run it on a wide range of x86-compatible machines running Windows <whatever>. Without recompiling it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, I see what you mean. But that's not a natural law. If I specify the cpu to be a pentium 4 northwood, that's all the compiler needs to adhere to and optimize for. It may or may not select a different path when building for a different cpu.

Comment: @mafu So you are saying, that you want this when compiling for one, single specific CPU (well, perhaps some very narrow range of CPUs). I am failing to see any useful case for such a functionality. Probably compiler makers too. I would say you won't find it in any mainstream compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Fair enough - if this is entirely unsupported and in fact impossible with any major compiler, then that's the answer to this question. I'm just wondering if there is some trick to do it still.

Comment: @mafu You usually do stuff like this with conditional compilation as the answers suggest. You can have it more fine-grained - like based on the presence of specific hardware (e.g. FPU), ISA extensions and such. Well, some of these can be even detected in the runtime.

Comment: Suppose one needs a quick function that will return 1 for all valid objects meeting some criterion, and 0 for most things that are not valid objects meeting that criterion; if the function returns 1, code will perform a slower check to determine if something is a valid object meeting the criterion.  In all valid objects both `int1*int2` and `int3*int4` will fit wthin the range of `int`, and in objects meeting the criterion `int1*int2 < int3*int4`.  On some platforms, evaluating `(long)int1*int2 < (long)int3*int4` may be faster than computing...

Comment: `(int)((unsigned)int1*int2) < (int)((unsigned)int3*int4)`, and both functions would satisfy application requirements despite the fact that for some values they would yield different results for some things that are not valid objects.  The only way a compiler could know that either way of performing the computation would be acceptable would be if there were some means by which the programmer could specify that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: There are many "problems" which have more than one correct solution.  If feeding some particular inputs to a function will sometimes cause it to yield correct solution X, and sometimes cause it to yield correct solution Y, such behavior may complicate tasks like regression testing, but letting a compiler choose the most efficient means of *satisfying application requirements* would often be better than requiring that programmers guess at which one of the possible satisfactory ways of processing a construct could be processed most efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros for that purpose, those are defined by the compilers on their respective operating systems. By using the following code, only those functions are executed which is appropriate for respective OS, eg., if the code is executing under Windows OS, `function_for_windows()` will execute **ONLY**.

```c
#if defined __linux__ || defined linux || defined __linux
                function_for_linux();
#elif _WIN32 || defined _WIN64 || defined __CYGWIN__
                function_for_windows();
#elif defined __unix__ || defined __unix || defined unix
                function_for_unix();
#elif defined __APPLE__ || defined __MACH__
                function_for_mac();
#elif defined __ANDROID__
                function_for_android();
#endif
```

Then, after that you can conclude the faster one.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to a different question.

Comment: @jarmod I can see how it is related to the question. Some explanation could be beneficial though

Comment: I'm definitely open to an explanation. The problem, as I understand it, is how can the compiler inject code that will allow the running app to pre-determine the optimal path among various available paths. It's not to solve "I know path A is better on Linux, path B is better on Win64, ..., so choose the relevant path". But maybe I mis-read the answer.

Comment: I'm fine with static analysis during compilation. There is no need for any dynamic benchmarking or something like that. The OS should have no impact, only the hardware should.

Comment: @jarmod When you compile your files, the compiler has pre-defined macros like `__linux__`, and after compiling only those functions or *code* are converted to machine code which lies under the macro definition.

Comment: @mafu Are you going to run your code on multiple hardware? And you want the compiler to automatically select a section of your code which will perform better on a respective hardware??

Comment: Right, I know that but the distinction that needs to be made here is more fine-grained than that afaik. For a given OS, there may be multiple potential paths to choose from and it's the compiler that needs to determine which, because of some knowledge it has about the targeted runtime environment (availability of GPU or hyper-threading, for example).

Comment: @Darth-CodeX agreed. Interesting question though, as we can see from the lengthy debate.

Comment: Absolutely, if you think it's a positive contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-fprofile-generate` option to generate profiling information when you compile the program, and then use the `-fprofile-use` option to use that information when you compile the program again with optimizations.

```bash
gcc -O3 -fprofile-generate test.c -o test
./test < input.txt
gcc -O3 -fprofile-use test.c -o test
```

- The first command enables profiling during program compilation and saves the profiling data in files with the `.gcda` extension.
- With representative inputs, the second command runs the program and produces profile data that is saved in files with the `.gcno` extension. [*OPTIONAL if your program doesn't need any inputs.*]
- The third command re-compiles the program with the aid of the profiling data to optimize it.

<sup>source: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html</sup>

<sup>source: https://www.google.com/search?q=fprofile-generate&sitesearch=man7.org%2Flinux%2Fman-pages&sa=Search+online+pages</sup>

Comment: Well, that's nice, but it is just an optimization method. It won't change code-paths based on the profiling info...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, for that some extensive research is required, based on the question this is what I found on several google searches

Comment: @EugeneSh. One can solve this question if he has some source code provided, and different machines

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark different versions on your platforms then choose the fastest one for the particular one and use `#if`s

```
#define PLATFORM2

/*...*/

#if defined(PLATFORM1)
   code_for_platform1();
#elif defined(PLATFORM2)
   code_for_platform2();
#else
   code_for_platform3();
#endif
```